# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when refreshing the overridden new tab in a Chrome Extension built with Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-router

I am developing a Chrome Extension using Angular. The extension override the "newtab" and it loads in a subdirectory "NewTab" (I set "baseHref": "/NewTab/" and it works fine). The new tab works but when I refresh the page it does not and it shows ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

I believe this is because the angular router rewrite "/index.html" to "/" (I can see this behaviour when testing with ng serve) and doing so, when refreshing the page, the browser tries to open chrome-extension://[extension_id]/NewTab/ instead chrome-extension://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NewTab/index.html breaking it.

Is it possible to set the angular router to NOT remove index.html from the url?Or is there any other work around for this?

Comment: Try switching the router into hash mode.

Comment: thanks, I tried to switch to thePathLocationStrategy but the result is the same, when refreshing the browser tries to open chrome-extension://[extension_id]/NewTab/ # resulting in the same error

Comment: sorry I wrote the wrong one, in the test above I used HashLocationStrategy